# Cookies are being deleted

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, cookies

I have an asp.net mvc application and I have this strange thing that is happening and I don't know why.

**Context:**

I have a page that allows the user draw and edit images. This page has a feature that each 5 minutes, she made a ajax call to the server using *jquery*, saving the current state of the project on the database and another call to save an image of the project that is storage in a proper place.

**Problem:**

With the browser minimized, when this feature is launched, after the ajax call to the server, the *cookie* Customer is *deleted*. But when the chrome is maximized, this works fine.

**Notes:**

1. This only happens when the browser is minimized
2. This is happening, at least, in chrome and firefox.
3. This is only happens on the production environment. On my local machine and on visual studio i cannot reproduce the issue
4. The asp.net session cookie is mantainned

I know that is difficult for you to help only with this information, but, if you can give me clues it will be really helpful. I'm trying to expose the problem so we can match similar issues to find the best solution for this case.

Thank you in advance

**[EDIT]**:

I have some new about the issue:

1. Using Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit);
2. Firefox quantum 57.0 (64-bit);
3. Contrary that I first thought, this is happens even if the browser is not minimized and precisely 3 mints after the page load (if I call the function)
4. The cookie are not being deleted but the content of the cookie is:
   [image]
5. This is a asp.net web application
6. The console does not gives any errors
7. The version of query is 2.1.3
8. Follows the `jquery` call code:

   ```
   makeAjaxCall(ajaxData) {
   var localData = ajaxData.data ? ajaxData.data : {},
       urlVariables = {};

   localData.cmd = ajaxData.cmd;

   var controlerURL = ajaxData.uploadUrl ? HelperJSViewBag.getValue("ajaxCAllUploadURL") : ajaxData.controller;

   if (typeof ajaxData.data.urlVariables == "undefined")
       ajaxData.data.urlVariables = [];

   let editorVersion = "";
   let forceEditorVersion = "";

   if (typeof UrlParameters != "undefined") {
       editorVersion = UrlParameters.getInstance().editorVersion;
       forceEditorVersion = UrlParameters.getInstance().forceEditorVersion;
   }
   else if (typeof HLinks != "undefined") {
       editorVersion = HLinks.getUrlVariable("editorVersion");
       forceEditorVersion = HLinks.getUrlVariable("forceEditorVersion");
   }

   if (editorVersion.length > 0)
       ajaxData.data.urlVariables.push({
           name: "editorVersion",
           value: editorVersion,
       });

   if (forceEditorVersion.length > 0)
       ajaxData.data.urlVariables.push({
           name: "forceEditorVersion",
           value: forceEditorVersion,
       });

   if (typeof ajaxData.data.urlVariables != "undefined" && ajaxData.data.urlVariables.length > 0)
       for (var i = 0; i < ajaxData.data.urlVariables.length; i++)
           urlVariables[ajaxData.data.urlVariables[i].name] = ajaxData.data.urlVariables[i].value;

   localData = this.fillLocalData(localData);

   return $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: localData,
       url: controlerURL + "?" + $.param(urlVariables),
       success: function (data) {
           try {
               var result = JSON.parse(data),
                   status = result.status;

               delete result.status
               switch (status) {
                   case 1: ajaxData.sucess && ajaxData.sucess(result.data); break;
                   case 2: ajaxData.insucess && ajaxData.insucess(ajaxData.errorHandler && ajaxData.errorHandler.handle && ajaxData.errorHandler.handle(result)); break;
               }
           }
           catch (ex) {
               ajaxData.insucess && ajaxData.insucess(ajaxData.errorHandler && ajaxData.errorHandler.handle && ajaxData.errorHandler.handle(ex));
           }
       },
       error: function (data) {
           ajaxData.insucess && ajaxData.insucess(ajaxData.errorHandler && ajaxData.errorHandler.handle && ajaxData.errorHandler.handle(data));
       }
   });
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you enable the network tab and then minimize the browser? Also put console.log with time print so you know what is happening, see if for some reason the session times out or the call is not made? I assume you are using setTimeout or setInterval? Whatever the case add logging and check console after minimizing

Comment: As this is related to drawings, I guess there may be some problem in reading the screen when minimized? If it happens that you delete the cookie before making the ajax call, then a failure in ajax call may result in cookie being deleted?

Comment: What code are you using to generate the cookie? Do you encounter any console errors when this happens? What version of Chrome and FF are you using for testing?

Comment: share your code to determine the errors

Comment: @cytsunny Please check the edit. I made several tests and I find out more info

Comment: @Twisty I shared the part of the code that I think could be the origin of the problem

Comment: @FaizanRupani I already made change on the post so I could include some code

Comment: @RicardoRocha I do not see where the cookie is created or updated. This would suggest that your cookie data is being created, managed, and updated by your ASP.NET code and not the JS. The 3 hour time period suggests that a timeout is triggering this change somewhere. The cookie does not seem to expire, but is somehow updated and the content is set to `""`.

Comment: Please post the code where the cookie "Customer" is created and/or managed.  Right now, all I see is JS and jQuery code with no references to cookies therein.

Comment: You are being cookie jacked by the cookie collector. It looks like when you minimize your browser, it is calling something to refresh your 'namespace cookie' and delete it. I would avoid cookies as much as possible, at least make them https and it shouldn't be "deleted".

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see your code on the ASP.NET side, but without that, I can only guess: perhaps check to see if you are setting a cookie expiration date? Here is an example of a cookie that is created with 1 day expiration:

```
Dim myCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("Customer")
myCookie.Expires = Now.AddDays(1)
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie)
```

If you omit myCookie.Expires property, the cookie "will expire when the user session expires", ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0):

1. you can increase the expiration time of your Cookies (Within the code where you are creating cookies).
2. You can use `localStorage`  in your code instead of Cookies  to hold the value.

For examlpe `localStorage.setItem` to set   value and  `localStorage.getItem` to get the value from local storage.